# Select DISTINCT values form two tables and comparing those two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables called USERS and EMP.

```
 USERS
-------

userid | username | useraddress
--------------------------------
   1   | U1       | ADD1 
   2   | U2       | ADD2 
   3   | U3       | ADD3
   4   | U4       | ADD4

  EMP
-------

empid | empname 
-----------------
 1    | emp1
 2    | emp2
 3    | emp3
```

these are the table no I want to see like this

If empid = userid then show the username and useraddress as a output

what is the query for that..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select u.username, u.useraddress
from EMP e
inner join USERS u
on e.empid = u.userid
```

But you may want to show all the Employees, regardless of if they are users, then you need a left join:

```
select u.username, u.useraddress
from EMP e
left join USERS u
on e.empid = u.userid
```

You could hide the fact that non matching Employees will show `NULL` by doing this:

```
select IFNULL(u.username, 'N/A'), IFNULL(u.useraddress, 'N/A')
from EMP e
left join USERS u
on e.empid = u.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when e.empid = u.userid 
            then concat(username, ' ', useraddress)
            else empname
       end as name
from users u
full outer join emp e on e.empid = u.userid
```

Comment: This is a slightly different result you get. I guess it depends on how you interpret the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.username, u.useraddress 
FROM USERS u INNER JOIN EMP e
 ON u.userid = e.empid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use query as below in MySQL:

```
SELECT USERS.username, EMP.useraddress FROM USERS,EMP WHERE EMP.id=USERS.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind both tables with Inner join query

```
select username as 'User Name',useraddress as 'User Address'
from USERS INNER JOIN EMP
on USERS.userid = EMP.empid;
```

but it will shows all records.And can join these query with left join for users on userid or with right join for emp on empid